# Laravel orm - Get top rows from relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relation

I have a categories table. every category has some posts.
I want to get categories with their last 10 posts.
So I tried this:

```
Category::query()->with(['posts' => function($q) {
     $q->take(10);
}])->get();
```

The problem is instead of putting 10 posts in each category record, it returns a total of 10 posts in all categories items.

Expected:

```
C1:
   id: 1
   posts: 10 post
C2:
   id: 2
   posts: 10 post
```

What I got

```
C1:
   id: 1
   posts: 4 post
C2:
   id: 2
   posts: 6 post
```

Answer (score -1):

Would try this version

```php
Category::with('posts')->get()->map(function($category) {
  $category->posts = $category->posts->take(10);
  return $category;
});

or optimize version try this package [link][1]


  


  [1]: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit
```

Comment: This is not optimized version, this will take all posts for each Category and then loop over the Categories and take only 10 first posts.

Comment: im added This Laravel Eloquent extension allows limiting the number of eager loading results per parent using package

Answer (score -1):

In fact, this is not a trivial task. The code you provided generates two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM categories;
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3, ...) LIMIT 10;
```

The 2nd query selects only 10 posts, not 10 per category.

To select 10 posts per category, you can make the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id) rn FROM posts
) posts
WHERE rn <= 10 AND category_id IN (1, 2, 3 ...);
```

Now let's implement it through Laravel's queryBuilder:

```
$result = Category::with(['posts' => static function($q) {
    $q->fromSub(
        Post::selectRaw('*, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id) rn'),
        'posts'
    )->where('rn', '<=', 10);
}])->get();
```

As a result, we still make only 2 queries and select only necessary posts (do not pull the entire table)

Comment: Thanks by what if I have some filter on posts? is this still working?

Comment: yes, of course, in the subquery (after selectRow) you can add any conditions and sorting